# PowerShell 5.1 Azure DevOps Server 2019 Why is last column header wrapping when there's plenty of room?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

PowerShell 5.1
Azure DevOps 2019

Below is a print screen of Azure DevOps release pipeline log results of a PowerShell script. The table was produced by `Invoke-Sqlcmd ... -OutputAs DataTables`.

Why is the last column header "Result" wrapping when there's plenty of room?

```
 return Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Sql -ServerInstance $Server -Database $Database -Credential $Credential -OutputAs DataTables
```

[image]

Comment: The web display have plenty of room. The console window it was printed in must have a smaller width and thus, when displayed in the web, you get a representation of what the console printed. This is my guess.

Answer (score 2):

Why? Your console has a max width!

Run this in your shell:

```
$host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize.Width
$host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Width
# These are likely be the same
```

Then grab your original output from the shell and paste it into VSCode or any text editor that counts columns. Put your cursor on the last character on the right. That number should match your width.